# How can I get a count of all child locations (including indirect) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

On pure SQL I get the result as I expect - the id of the location and the number of all child locations (direct and indirect):

```
select id, (with recursive
   children as (
       select loc.id, loc.parent_id
       from "location" as loc
       where loc.parent_id = "location".id

       union

       select loc.id, loc.parent_id
       from "location" as loc
       join children on children.id = "loc".parent_id
)
select count(*) from children)
from "location";
```

But with SQLAlchemy I only get the number of direct child locations:

```
    top_query = Location.query.cte('cte', recursive=True)

    top_aliased = aliased(top_query, name='top_aliased')
    bottom_aliased = aliased(Location, name='bottom_aliased')

    q = top_query.union(self.session.query(bottom_aliased).filter(bottom_aliased.parent_id == top_aliased.c.id))

    q = self.session \
        .query(func.count(q.c.id)) \
        .filter(q.c.parent_id == Location.id) \
        .group_by(q.c.parent_id)

    all_locations = Location.query.with_entities(Location.id, q.label('child_count')).all()
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

I would like to get the number of all child locations, including indirect locations (child of childs)

Comment: @python_user Only 2 columns really matter here: `id` and `parent_id` 

`class Location(db.Model, BaseModelMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'location'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('location.id'))`

Comment: Your `filter` is in the wrong place. To me it looks like you are filtering the result of the CTE, not the top half.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Yes, that's right. I shouldn't have grouped and filtered in the end result. Also I shouldn't have done a filter in the query, which is part of UNION. There I should have done a JOIN on top_query